# Lazy vs init for singleton design in swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io library to add the real-time feature to my app, and I'm using Singleton design

```
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    func establishConnection() {
       socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
       socket.connect()

    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

}
```

So technically whenever my app loads up `socket` cannot be nil or else it will crash. I found two solutions that could solve this problem

1. **Lazy**

   ```
   lazy var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
   ```

By using this method `socket` will never be nil, because it will always be initialized. But the problem with this method is that if creating SocketIOClient is not cheap then it would be a great method to use.

2. **Init()**

   ```
   class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

       static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

       let socket: SocketIOClient!



   init() {
           super.init()
           socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
     }
   }
   ```

By using this method, I'm a little bit confused because I don't initially create the SocketIOManager object like

```
let socket = SocketIOManager()
```

because if I'm not mistaken the socket will get initialized if only object is created, and I'm not sure about using `init()` in the Singleton design

Which method is suitable for my use case?

Answer (score 7):

In Swift globals, including static members of classes are **lazy** by default so this is correct:

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let socket: SocketIOClient!

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
  }
}
```

Note the **private** on the init to prevent anyone else from trying to instantiate this class, since its a singleton.

Comment: I got this error `Property 'self.socket' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: The line `socket = SocketIOClient(soc....` needs to be above `super.init()` and then `socket` does not need to be implicitly unwrapped. Edit: assuming `SocketIOClient(socketURL: config)` is not a failable initializer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254):

> Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They are guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.

The recommended way is to declare the socket as non-optional, first initialize the property and then call `super`

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let socket: SocketIOClient

    init() {
        socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Alternatively initialize `socket` with a closure but this requires that there is no access to other properties of the same class.

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let socket: SocketIOClient = {
         return SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "https://server.com/path")!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
    }()
}
```

Or if `mainURL` is declared as constant in the same class you could initialize `socket` lazily. That means also the socket will be initialized on **its** first access.

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let mainURL = URL(string: "https://server.com/path")!

    lazy var socket: SocketIOClient = {
         return SocketIOClient(socketURL: mainURL, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
    }()
}
```

In the second and third case an extra `init` method is not needed.

Comment: What if `getToken()` doesn't exist then it will not establishConnection because initially the socket is loaded without the token. How do I reinitialized the socket?

Comment: Nobody can read your mind. What is `getToken()`? If you need an ad hoc  connection a singleton might be the wrong solution. Or you you have to make the socket `var` and create a new one on demand.

Comment: `"token"` in the init function at the `.connectParams`. My bad for using wrong word